# Collection of examples of course designs with the flaws pointed out and explained?

Tags: reference-request, course-design

We have a course on didactics in the curriculum, accomplishing which we should be able to evaluate courses and design our ones. I wonder if there is a collection of good course examples or examples of reviewing/evaluating a course with flaws exposed. Can I look at courses as a math/physics student looks at solved problems from the end of the book?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit?  I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what you're asking about.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're asking for a set of examples of course designs with the flaws pointed out and explained? Is that right?

Comment: @ff524 You basically repeat my words. This is what I am asking indeed :)

Comment: My question would be what exactly you mean by course design: a syllabus of topics to cover? an overall teaching strategy or philosophy? a "ready to go" course complete with lecture notes, exercises, and exams?

Comment: @user37208 By course design I mean the delivery. I think that didactics abstracts away from subject and just concentrates on the form. So, it cannot discuss the subject/content. It discusses the ability of teacher to fill students with content, is he using right techniques for that or not, does he communicate with students enough or not. Actually, I just started. I cannot tell you for sure. :) I expect that people who are familiar with the didactics and course designs should know better what is expected :)